# Xcode does not show window when opened from macOS dock

Tags: xcode

When I try to open Xcode via macOS Dock, there *is* a dot at the bottom of the app icon, but it isn't opening any windows. So I have to open the window by clicking File > Open...
If it isn't normal, then please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen or had this issue, but I did find this source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3854586

"In Xcode 4 choose Window > Welcome (or command - shift - 1) to Xcode to open the welcome window that gives you an option to create a new Xcode project. Select the Show this window when Xcode launches checkbox to have the welcome window open when you launch Xcode."

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but the workaround does not work for me - there is no option to “show this window on start” in XCode 15

I am amazed no one else has complained

I think it could maybe be an issue with the Xcode icon size? I think I can distinguish a tiny blue dot where it should be displayed but it just isn’t big enough to be able to register a click

**Edit** Actually I just upgraded to MacOS 14.1.2 and it seems fixed